# Event no trabaja Producción

Tags: laravel, websocket, forge

Buen dia, tengo un proyecto que envía un evento al enviar un mensaje, funciona bien en local, pero en producción nunca envía el evento, intente todo, hice un dump y la data llega al evento pero no dispara nunca, como menciono **solo en producción**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

    class NewMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
    {
        use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    
        /**
         * Create a new event instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public $data;
    
        public function __construct($data)
        {
            $this->data = $data;
        }
    
        public function broadcastOn()
        {
          return ['private-chatify'];
        }
    
        public function broadcastAs()
        {
          return 'client-messaging';
        }
    }
```

y lo uso aquí en mi controlador.

```
 use App\Events\NewMessage as sendMsg;

$message =  [
                'from_id' => Auth::user()->id,
                'to_id' => $request['id'],
                'type' => $request['type'],
                'message' => Chatify::messageCard($messageData, 'default')
            ];
            $success = event(new sendMsg($message));
```

Para finalizar uso forge para pasarlo a producción, tal vez sea alguna configuración ahi. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Ya registraste el event listener en el EventServiceProvider?

Comment: Error de mi jefe, en el enviroment de produccion habia dejado el BROADCAST_DRIVER en log, cuando debí poner pusher que es lo que uso. Gracias.

Comment: Considera publicar tu solución, así la pregunta no queda abierta

Answer (score 0):

El broadcast que uso `pusher` por lo cual dentro del `.env` debio colocarse `BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher`, lo cual si lo tenia configurado dentro del local, pero en el de prueba esto no era asi, se configuro, y esto quedo solucionado.

Adicional, configure en el enviroment un texto con la ruta de mi socket y lo agregue aqui como `HOST_PUSHER`

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'host' => env('HOST_PUSHER'),
                'encrypted' => false,
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'https',
                'curl_options' => [
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                ],
                'useTLS' => false
            ],
        ],
```